# Склоняется ли название ресторана "Турандот"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение-имён-собственных

Турандот — имя китайской принцессы (и оно, разумеется, не склоняется). В её честь в Москве назван ресторан, но никто из персонала этого заведения не склоняет его название. Хотелось бы услышать мнение эксперта. Если я правильно понимаю, в данном случае произошёл переход имени существительного из одного рода в другой: из женского в мужской.

Comment: На основании чего вы решили, что "произошёл переход"? Не склоняют же. Или персонал не склоняет, а все остальные таки да? Поясните.

Answer (score 1):

> данном случае произошёл переход имени существительного из одного рода
>   в другой

Да не должно бы... Я в том ресторане не был, но если такое произошло, это противоречит общим принципам языковых процессов. Не очень, правда, понятно, из чего вы делаете такой вывод.

Давайте на примерах. Колхоз "Победа". "Победа" перешло в м.р.? Да никогда. 
У вас, конечно, не столь прозрачный случай, ибо у нас имя собственное имеет грамматические признаки мужского рода (нулевое окончание), но в целом все равно весьма странно ожидать такого превращения.

**UPD**
@Alex_ander дал убийственный контрпример - (автомобиль) "Мерседес". Ну что тут сказать... Да, в лингвистике нет правил без исключений. Но стоит все-таки учитывать, что слово это прошло длительный период адаптации, обкатки языком, прежде чем стать грамматическим трансгендером.

Answer (score 1):

Из Интернета: *Девочки, здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, у меня завтра **в "Турандоте**" фотосессия, со мной ещё 14 человек...*

**В разговорном стиле** название склоняется (не все же помнят про принцессу). Да и удобнее так говорить, например: мы собираемся (пойти) в "Турандот" — мы собираемся (встретиться) в "Турандоте". Смысл у этих предложений разный, и при отсутствии склонения возможно неоднозначное понимание.

Поэтому в разговорной речи встречаются оба варината. Тогда название с нулевым твердым окончанием **склоняется по образцу** существительного мужского рода.

Answer (score 0):

Если ресторан назван именно в честь китайской принцессы - то не склоняется.

Если просто назван этим именем (если оно может быть мужским) - то можно склонять.

По информации из вопроса ресторан назван в честь принцессы. А принцесса в принца не превратится...

Пример:

`Ресторан "Надежда".` (имя в мужское не превращается)

Comment: А если ресторан (кабак) называется "Шапокляк", "Кардашьян" или "Изергиль" - тоже нужно дамскую честь учесть? Едва ли посетителям, приехавшим в "Мерседесе" (и такая девушка была) есть дело до этимологии: это прежде всего ресторан, пусть и названный откуда-то знакомым словом; мужской род коррелирует здесь с видовым наименованием заведения. Если кто-то скажет, что напился вчера в "Турандот", то очень многие подумают, что "вдрабадан".

Comment: ))))))) Может, это и не практично, но по логике правильно. Склонение зависит от оригинала. Но решение о изменении рода за владельцами заведения. На практике это зависит от звучания склонений. Таким же образом будут решать и посетители заведения, независимо от мнения владельцев.

Comment: @Alex_ander *называется "Шапокляк"* - Вы таки будете смяться, но урожденная Шапокляк - мужского рода. Это мужской головной убор, складной цилиндр.   А за "Мерседес" - огромное-преогромное спасибо. Вертелося у меня в голове, что есть какой-то пример на эту тему, да не мог вспомнить.